# Match WIldcard to specific word length.

Tags: microsoft-word, search, wildcards

So when I use wild cards on Microsoft Word I have something like
[A-B]{2}

It works as expected and capture groups of two letters as wanted. 
My issue is that it also captures 3 letter and larger words. Is it possible to make it so that maybe it checks for a least one space after the second letter or that the word is only two letters long in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **<** and **>** to match beginning and end of a word.

The final pattern in your case is:

```
<[A-B]{2}>
```